# Backtick not working with the eslint/prettier recommended configuration

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

This is my .eslintrc.js

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    "google",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
  ],
  parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  parserOptions: {
    project: ["./tsconfig.json", "./tsconfig.dev.json"],
    sourceType: "module",
    tsconfigRootDir: __dirname,
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    "/lib/**/*", // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: ["@typescript-eslint", "import", "prettier"],
  rules: {`your text`
    "prettier/prettier": ["error", { endOfLine: "auto" }],
    quotes: ["error", "double", "avoid-escape"],
    "import/no-unresolved": 0,
    "@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any": "off",
  },
};
```

Also this is my prettier config:

```
{
  "singleQuote": false,
  "printWidth": 120
}
```

And I'm still getting this error:
[image]

I want my VSCode to let me use backticks and double quotes at the same time

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/quotes#allowtemplateliterals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/quotes#allowtemplateliterals

You need

```
   quotes: ["error", "double", { "allowTemplateLiterals": true }]
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, that was actually the problem, now it's working fine

Comment: Mark it as an answer (green tick) if this is one